# Why do no breakpoints get hit?

Tags: google-chrome

I have added several breakpoints but the code continues and plays the sound - line 449.
What am I doing wrong?
[image: Source with breakpoints]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is This a local environment? Try to clear the cache and run the code again from the beginning. Sometimes when you have compilation problem chrome takes the last working version.